# Image file name increment problem of a bot scraper

Tags: python

My goal is to create a small Python program which aims to retrieve an image every five minutes on a website via the url of the image. So far everything works but the constraint is to add +1 to each new image saved in the directory, otherwise the new image retrieved will replace the old one in the directory. So you need an increment. My program works but every five minutes the new image replaces the old one since they have the same name. My increment in the filename does not work.

Here is my Python program:

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import urllib.request
import time
import os 
import os.path

i = 0

while True:
    urllib.request.urlretrieve("https://url/image.jpg", "image.jpg")
    
    while os.path.exists("image%i.jpg"):
     i = i + 1
  
    time.sleep(300)
```

Thank you in advance for your help !

Answer (score 0):

You can use f-string, they are an easy way to format strings in python:

They work like that: [Python F-String Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html)

```
name = "Tom"

print(f"Hello {name}")

> Hello Tom
```

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import urllib.request
import time
import os 
import os.path

image_count = 0

while True:
    urllib.request.urlretrieve("https://url/image.jpg", "image.jpg")
    
    while os.path.exists(f"image-{image_count}.jpg"):
    image_count += 1
  
    time.sleep(300)
```

Comment: First of all thank you for answering my problem. Unfortunately the program stops at "image_count" with the error : IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: Hi @BTB, don't copy and paste my answer, rather typ it: I used the spacebar for intendation not the TAB-Key which python only recognises! Then it should work fine:)

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the file check before the file save, then make sure to also append that I value to the save location.

```py
i = 0
while True:
    while os.path.exists(f"image{str(i)}.jpg"):
        i +=1
    urllib.request.urlretrieve("https://url/image.jpg", f"image{str(i)}.jpg")
    time.sleep(300)
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my problem. However, the program stores the name of the variable "%i" directly in the file name. So the program always replaces the same file name with "image%i.jpg". Ultimately the program does the same as before.

Comment: @BTB That is my mistake, I edited the post to use an f-string and that should help!

Comment: The program works ! Thank you again for your help !